# Datetime nullable issue

Tags: c#, datetime, null

I am sending `datetime to a function` like:

`MyFunction((DateTime)MethodDateTime);`

Whereas my `MethodDateTime` is of `DateTime` datatype and contains `null` value.

Because of this while executing, it gives me error `nullable object must have a value`.

My Functions is this:

```
MyFunction(DateTime abc)
{
    // Statements
}
```

So after surfing, what i can understand that i am forcing null to datetime. But this is my issue, sometimes i get null value as datetime, so how to deal with it?

Also when i am passing `datetime` directly it says

1. `The best overloaded method match for 'Big.Classes.QStr.MyFunction(System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments`
2. `cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'`

So because of this i am doing `(DateTime)MethodDateTime`

Declaration and Initialization for my datetime is `DateTime? MethodDateTime = null;`

**EDIT:**

Major declaration i have made is:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get's or set's the MethodDateTime. If no MethodDateTime is there, this
    /// attribute is null.
    /// </summary>
    DateTime? MethodDateTime
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you change the method signature to receive a DateTime?  ?

Comment: Actually i have been using this property since long while coding. Don't want to change otherwise, i will be forced to change so many codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply change the method signature to receive a nullable DateTime

```
MyFunction(DateTime? abc)
{
    if(abc.HasValue)
    {
        // your previous code
    }
    else
    {
       // Handle the NULL case
    }
}
```

However, if you really don't want to change your previous code you could simply add another method with the same name but with a nullable datetime

```
MyFunction(DateTime? abc)
{
     Console.WriteLine("NULLABLE version called");
}

MyFunction(DateTime abc)
{
     Console.WriteLine("NOT NULLABLE version called");
}
```

In this way the framework will call the correct method looking at the datatype of the variable passed

Comment: Ok this works for me :) Gosh why it didn't came to my mind. Very true... this is basic, thanks a million....

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your function with parameter of type `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime` so it's a `nullable`.

```
MyFunction(DateTime? abc)
{
   // Statements
}
```

That's the only way to work with `DateTime` if you need to handle possible null values. With nullable types you have the properties `HasValue` (preferred to checking against `null`) and `Value`, for example:

```
MyFunction(DateTime? abc)
{
   if(abc.HasValue)
   {
     DateTime myDate = abc.Value;
   } else {
     // abc is null
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks brother it removed the error, let me check if program is working fine. Anyways its a nice lesson for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can go with nullable datetime **[DateTime?](http://www.dotnetperls.com/nullable-datetime)**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you do not want to send in DateTime as a nullable object to MyFunction. Then you have to first check if it is null and then send in the value.

```
if(MethodDateTime.HasValue)
{
   MyFunction(MethodDateTime.Value);
}
else
{
   // handle this case somehow
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` values cannot hold `null`. `Nullable<DateTime>` (which is the same thing as `DateTime?`) is essentially a wrapper class, that allows you to store a `ValueType` or a null value.

You either need to test your DateTime? value:

```
if(MethodDateTime == null)
    MyFunction(DateTime.MinValue) //Pass in a sentinal value
```

or change your method to allow nullables:

```
MyFunction(DateTime? abc)
{
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Whereas my MethodDateTime is of DateTime datatype and contains null value."

Nope, it is `DateTime?` and not `DateTime`, wich is short for `System.Nullable<DateTime>` The Error occurs when you cast it from `DateTime?` to `DateTime` and it has no value.

```
if( MethodDateTime.HasValue)
{
    MyFunction(MethodDateTime.Value);
}
else
{
    //Handle error
}
```