# Nullable<System.DateTime> error on IIS ,but working well on production enviroment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I using this on my C# code. It is working well on visual studio. Example function be like

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult InsertOCMain(List<Stock> ocarrays,string ocno, DateTime ocdate,DateTime cusdate, Guid compid, string prodval, string pf, string total, string igst,string sptaxlabel,decimal sptax, string modeofdespatch, string paymentterms, string grandtotal,string refn,string pino,string cgst, string sgst,string discountprod,decimal spldiscount, string editoption,string couriercharge, string roundoff, string comments)
{
    
    var isocmainExists = db.OC_Main.Any(x => x.OC_No == ocno);
    if (isocmainExists)
    {
        if (editoption == "yes")
        {
            var editoc = db.OC_Main.Where(a => a.OC_No == ocno).FirstOrDefault();
            HttpCookie cookie1 = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("Userid");
            string organise = cookie1.Value;
            System.Guid org;
            org = new Guid(organise);
            string datestring = ocdate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string custdate = cusdate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        

 var txtocno = $('#txtpno').val();

            var ocdate = $('#txtdate').val(); 

var cusdate = $('#txtcusdate').val(); var compid = c; var prodval = $('#prdval').val(); var pf = $('#pf').val(); var total = $('#total').val();
            var igst = ig; var cgst = cg; var sgst = sg; var grandtotal = $('#grdtot').val(); var refn = $('#txtrefno').val();
            var pino = $('#Pino option:selected').text(); var discountprod = proddisc; var spldiscount = spldisc; var editoption = editopt;
            var roundoff = $('#roundoff').val(); var comments = $('#mainterms').val(); var modeofdespatch = $('#txtmodeofdespatch').val(); var paymentterms = $('#txtpaymentterms').val();
            if (pf == "") {
                pf = "0.00";
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/OC/InsertOCMain",
                data: JSON.stringify({ ocarrays, ocno: txtocno, ocdate: ocdate, cusdate: cusdate, compid: compid, prodval: prodval, pf: pf, total: total, igst: igst, cgst: cgst, sgst: sgst, sptaxlabel: sptaxlabel, sptax: sptax, modeofdespatch: modeofdespatch, paymentterms: paymentterms, grandtotal: grandtotal, refn: refn, pino: pino, discountprod: discountprod, spldiscount: spldiscount, editoption: editoption, couriercharge: couriercharge, roundoff: roundoff, comments: comments }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
```

They above code working well on production enviroment but it not working on IIS. i have error  be like that

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'ocdate' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult InsertOCMain(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CRMWebApp.Models.Stock], System.String, System.DateTime, System.DateTime, System.Guid, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.Decimal, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.Decimal, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String)' in 'CRMWebApp.Areas.CRM.Controllers.OCController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

How to solve this issue on IIS

Comment: The issue is not in your controller code, it is a response to a http request that is missing a value for the date parameter. Include the request message that you are sending and we can help explain what is wrong.

Comment: _"They above code working well on production enviroment"_ - maybe because in production you always pass the correct value? _"but it not working on IIS"_ -  are you using IIS in prod? I would argue that the error message is pretty straightforward and my guess would be it has nothing to do with IIS.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller _"it is a response to a http request that is missing a value for the date parameter"_ - why do you think that?

Comment: Pretty much what the error says: `ocdate` has a null value but the method is expecting a value. So what are you calling the method with? Also if OP think IIS is an issue, then this is a runtime error, not a compile time error

Comment: All code added for reference.@ChrisSchaller

Comment: Use browser developer tools or network monitoring tools to inspect the request being sent to the server. Verify that the ocdate parameter is included in the request payload and has a valid value.

Comment: yes it send ocdate ,but still error. Same system visual studion this code work perfectly but via IIS it have error.

Comment: My understanding is that when the method named 'InsertOCMain' is called, the value passed to the 'ocdate' parameter is null, and the 'ocdate' parameter is a non-nullable type 'System.DateTime'.
You need to provide a non-null valid datetime value for the 'ocdate' parameter when calling the 'InsertOCMain' method. If 'ocdate' is optional and can be nullable, consider changing its type to DateTime? (nullable DateTime) in your action method signature. This will allow the parameter to accept null values if needed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715814/datetime-nullable-issue